# How do I receive data from a PHP echo to display using AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Simply said: How do I receive data from a PHP echo to display using AJAX?

I have the ability to use JQuery; however, I don't know if that would be right for the job or not.  I simply have a form in HTML which the user may input information, but as they are entering data, I want to check for availability against a database.  If the input checks and there's no problem, I don't want any text displayed, but if there's a problem then I want to display an error.  I currently have a sign-up form working with PHP and MySQL through a database, but I can't get the errors to echo out without having a page refresh.  Is there any way to show errors without refreshing?

HTML:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><h1>New to the site?</h1></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="login_text">Username:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="signup_username" value="<?php echo $username ?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="login_text">Password:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="password" class="inputs" name="signup_password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="login_text">Password <span style="color: #666666;">(repeat)</span>:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="password" class="inputs" name="signup_passwordrepeat"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="login_text">Email:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="signup_email" value="<?php echo $email ?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="signupbutton" class="subutton" style="font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;  font-size: 1.5em;  width: 265px;  height: 3em;" value="Sign Up!" name="signup_button"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
            $submit = $_POST["signup_button"];
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["signup_username"]);
            $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["signup_password"]);
            $repeatpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["signup_passwordrepeat"]);
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["signup_email"]);
            $date = date(m.d.y);

            if($submit) {  //If the form is submitted
                if($username && $password && $repeatpassword && $email) {  //If everything is filled out
                    //Check length of username
                    if(strlen($username) <= 16) {
                        $usercheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artists WHERE username='$username'");
                        $usernum = mysql_num_rows($usercheck);

                        if($usernum == 0) {  //Check for availability of username
                            $emailcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artists WHERE email='$email'");
                            $emailnum = mysql_num_rows($emailcheck);

                            if($emailnum == 0) {  //Check for availability of email address
                                if($password == $repeatpassword) {  //Check for identical password input
                                    //Encrypt password
                                    $password = sha1($password);
                                    $repeatpassword = sha1($repeatpassword);

                                    //REGISTER
                                    $register = mysql_query("INSERT INTO artists VALUES ('', '', '$username', '$password', '$email', '', '$date')");
                                    echo("Registration successful, please log in on the right!");
                                }
                                else
                                    echo("The passwords don't match!");
                            }
                            else
                                echo("That email address has already been registered!");
                        }
                        else
                            echo("That username has already been registered!");
                    }
                    else
                        echo("The username you entered is too long!");
                }
                else
                    echo("Please fill out all fields!");
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: These are in same file by the way, they're BOTH in "index.php".

Comment: in javascript, you can just update the innerContent of an object by the id!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) is the standard validation system for jQuery and provides support for AJAX based validation (where it sends things back to the server to validate it and displays a message for you if it fails).

Answer (score 2):

put the message you want to echo in json eg

```
<?php echo json_encode(array('message_you_want' => 'your message here'));?>
```

then set dataType in your ajax call to json eg

```
dataType : 'json'
```

and then in your success function for your ajax you can pass the json object through eg

```
$.ajax({
 dataType: 'json',
 url : 'url',
 data : {/*data here*/},
 success: function(j)
 {
  //access your message like this
  alert(j.message)
 }
});
```

its also bad practice to nest your if statements like that. you should look into that

hope this helped